# Combining std::vector Default and Fill Constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I had a fairly quick question. The std::vector provides the following two constructors:

```
explicit vector( const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());      // default constructor

explicit vector( size_type count,                            // fill constructor
             const T& value = T(),
             const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

Is there any particular reason the default constructor is not implemented with a default value of 0 for the first parameter in the fill constructor? I can imagine there must be a reason but I can't immediately see one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you then can't pass just an `allocator`, without providing the `count` or default element (aka `value`) as well?

Putting `count` to `0` will result in ambiguity error.

Would be much more simpler if C++ had named params like Python. [Boost has such a library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/reference.html), but again that incurs some runtime overhead :( (can't remember how much right now) I often used this Lib in testing, but not where the performance is important...

Comment: I feel like there are a bunch of places in c++ where you have to just suck it up and supply extra arguments when you want to specify one that occurs later in the parameter list. One example is specifying the comparison function for `std::priority_queue` (in the template arguments). I guess they made the decision because specifying just the allocator is a really common use case?

Comment: @gowrath Yes, I sometimes really miss Python's named params :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that the constructors place different requirements on the type contained in the vector. To use the second one, the type must copy-constructible, and if you use the default argument for `value`, it must be default-constructible too. The first constructor places no such requirements on the contained type.

Note that the constructors you're showing in the question only existed until C++11. There, it was sufficient to differentiate those two scenarios (since any type stored in a `std::vector` had to be copy-constructible). C++11 introduced move semantics, and the second constructor was split further:

```
explicit vector(size_type count);

vector(
  size_type count,
  const T& value,
  const Allocator& alloc = Allocator()
);
```

That's because `std::vector` no longer requires its contained types to be copy-constructibe; move-constructibility is enough. Therefore the count-only constructor requires default constructibility (but not copy constructibility), and the count + prototype constructor requires copy constructibility (but not default constructibility).

---

The evolution of `std::vector` constructors is really quite complex. See [their page on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) to see how much they've evolved. That evolution includes adding an optional `allocator` parameter to the count-only constructor in C++14, which was (I assume) mistakenly omitted.